# Firebase not taking same package name for Release build variant

Tags: android, firebase

I have a Problem Regarding different Build Variant. 
I have made 3 Build variant with Beta,Debug and Release. I have also integrated OTP using Firebase.
When i try to run the app with debug or beta, the otp comes. but when i switch to release mode, the otp doesn't come.
and i got to know this is happening because of SHA-1 not updated in firebase release package name but when i try to connect it with release build variant, it still taking debug package name.
I tried every other solution but nothing works for me.

**check the package name even if i have set the build to release mode:**

[image: check the package name even if i have set the build to release mode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my own answer, as, debug app doesn't need any release key, but when i set my app to release, it generate a release mode, so, it need the original keyforandroid.jks, but i didn;t set the path for it. That's why the problem occurs.